# How to unset fields based on the fields' name with a "less than" condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to unset certain fields based on the name of the field (the key).

Say I have something like this:

```
{
    5: "cool",
    93: "cool",
    30: "cool",
    56: "cool"
}
```

How would I unset all fields with a value below, say, 40.

So the result should be:

```
{
    5: "cool",
    30: "cool"
}
```

I tried using the less than command on the whole field or using the positional operator but both of those failed.

```
collection.update_one(
        {"_id": id},
        {"$unset": {"blacklist.$": {"$lt": 40}}}
    )
```

I couldn't find anything online or on the docs so I am hoping to find some help here,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really use `$unset` like this, we can still achieve this using pipelined updates - with slightly more complicated syntax.

Our approach will be to turn our root object to an array using `$objectToArray`, iterate over it and filter all numeric keys under a certain threshold. then finally convert back to an object and update our document, like so:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
            },
            cond: {
              $cond: [
                {
                  $regexMatch: {
                    input: "$$this.k",
                    regex: "^[0-9]+$"
                  }
                },
                {
                  $lt: [
                    {
                      $toInt: "$$this.k"
                    },
                    40
                  ]
                },
                true
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gl3E5cc6Wb3)

Comment: I see you've used commands that are placed under the aggregation sections in the docs, something like ["$replaceRoot"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/).
Is this something that is generally possible to do within the update method, or is this case specific?
Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind my last question... I am looking much further into what I can do with aggregation and generally with mongodb due to this answer so I would like to thank you <3

Comment: It is with pipelined updates (added in version 4.2), notice the second argument is an array (a pipeline) and not a document per the usual syntax, worth mentioning not all aggregation stages are available, just ones that affect structure, Prior to version 4.2 you could not use the document values wtihin the update and you had to split it into 2 calls, read first then write

Answer (score 1):

Query

- into `[]` the `$$ROOT`
- filter the keys to be either `"_id"` or `< 40`
- back to object and
- replace root

*this removes all fields `>=40` , you can change the last `$lt` if you don't need this

*toms answer works and its more general, if you have mixed keys that some are numbers and some are not use toms way (this is slightly simpler but supposes that all fields are numbers except the "_id")

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70606894-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$replaceRoot":
  {"newRoot":
   {"$arrayToObject":
    [{"$filter":
      {"input":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"},
       "cond":
       {"$or":
        [{"$eq":["$$this.k", "_id"]},
         {"$lt":[{"$toInt":"$$this.k"}, 40]}]}}}]}}}])
```